# MemoryError when dividing NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pyaudio

I'm trying to calculate the impulse response of a signal. Here is the code:

```
def impulse_response(self):
    # Inverse filter:
    T = self.recorded_data.shape[0] / self.samplerate
    t = np.arange(0, T*self.samplerate - 1) / self.samplerate
    R = np.log(20/20000)
    k = np.exp(t*R/T).astype(np.float32)
    f = self.recorded_data[::-1] / k  # Gives an MemoryError
    # Impulse response:
    return sig.fftconvolve(self.recorded_data, f, mode="same")
```

The division when calculating the filter f gives an MemoryError.
`self.recorded_data` is a sine sweep of 15 sec and with a samplingrate of 44100Hz its 2822400 Bytes large. `k` is 2822396 Bytes large(both arrays are 32 bit floats). I didn't think these arrays would be a problem to divide as they aren't that large. Is there a problem with how the dividing is done? Maybe theres an more effective way to do it? Or should I use another datatype?

The array sizes I found by using https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nbytes.html

I get the same error when dividing NumPY arrays in my `transfer_function()` function, so I guess its the same problem.

I got the code from https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41696/calculating-the-inverse-filter-for-the-exponential-sine-sweep-method

By the way, my computer has 8GB of RAM.

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Are you sure about the dimensions? because 3MB is not a problem.

Comment: I got the dimensions using numpy.nbytes

Comment: Then it should work. Nothing here that makes the divide raise an out of memory.

Comment: What are the exact shapes of `k` and `self.recorded_data`?

Comment: Are you sure that the division is not broadcasting the array such that it becomes N * N  size with the division?

Comment: See for more info [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: What is the exact error message? Are you sure the division causes the error? Did you try without the `/k`?

Comment: *"I didn't think these arrays would be a problem to divide as they aren't that large."*  We need to know `self.recorded_data.shape`.  If, for example, that shape is (705600, 1) (i.e. the array is 2-d with a single column), and if `k` has shape (705599,), then when `self.recorded_data[::-1] / k` is computed, [*broadcasting*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) applies and the result has shape (705600, 705599).

Comment: I got it working now by removing `-1` from `t = np.arange(0, T*self.samplerate - 1) / self.samplerate`. Looking at the code i copied from I don't know how it got there! `k` should not be 1 sample shorter than `self.recorded_data` so I got this error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (661500,) (661499,)`. So I think you guys are correct that broadcasting was the problem. Dont know why I got an MemoryError in the first place though, since both arrays are 1-dimensional. I suspect I might have used some wrong input which i didnt manage to reproduce right now...

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now by removing `-1` from `t = np.arange(0, T*self.samplerate - 1) / self.samplerate`. Looking at the code I copied from I don't know how it got there! k should not be 1 sample shorter than self.recorded_data so I got this error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (661500,) (661499,)`. I must be more careful to doublecheck the dimenions of the data I'm working with...